# VBA Code to click a button on a webpage needed

Tags: vba

I need to be able to click a button through vba. Can someone help me with the code? For some reason, I am having difficulty making this work. I would be so grateful for any help. Thank you.

```html
<input type="submit" class="Button_PartnerStyle" value="TRACK IT" onclick="checkVariables()">
```

```vb
    Set arr = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("Button_PartnerStyle")
    For Each a In arr
        a.Click
    Next a
    Do Until ie.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
    Loop
    Set arr = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("Button_PartnerStyle")
    For Each a In arr
        If a.Value = "TRACK IT" Then
            a.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
    Do Until ie.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
    Loop
    Set arr = ie.Document.getElementsByName("Type")
    For Each a In arr
        If a.Value = "submit" Then
            a.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: You should include your current code.

Comment: use execscript : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536420(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Please add the appropriate tag for application you are using. There is the snippet of the VBA code only, add the entire macro. Describe what's wrong with your code. Share the target URL, and if you can't for some reasons - post the entire webpage html code.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html

This line of code is the key.

```
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit
```